# show that if $A$ is a σ-algebra then $σ(A)=A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that if $A$ is a $σ$-algebra then $σ(A)=A$

My proof:

$σ(A)=A \iff σ(A)\subset A\; \text{and} \;A \subset σ(A)$

We have always $A\subset σ(A)$ still to prove that $\sigma(A)\subset A$

note that $$\sigma(A):=\mathop{\bigcap}_{M\;is\;\sigma-Alg\\M\supseteq A}M$$
Since $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma(A)$ is the smallest one then $A \subset σ(A)$
Is my Proof correct?

Comment: Your proof that $\sigma(A)\subset A$ isn't clear and could stand to be fleshed out more.

Comment: I guess this works, but it's a little overcomplicated. I'd simply write the following set containments: $$A\subset\sigma(A)\subset\bigcap\limits_{M\; \sigma\text{ algebra }\supset A}M\subset A$$Where the last inequality is a result of $A\cap B\subset A$.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the second direction needs to be fleshed out more. Suppose that $a \in \sigma(A)$. Then, by definition $a\in \bigcap M$. But $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and contains itself, so $A$ is one of the $M$'s. This implies $a \in A$.

Comment: I fully agree with your comment and answer. But the wording makes it feels complicated in my opinion.